# Change the default browser which Mozilla prism uses

Tags: mozilla-prism

Each time I click on a link inside, it opens up in its own browser. How do I change the default browser to Firefox?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Prism is stripped down Firefox under the hood, that is why it is available in 2 flavours, FIREFOX plugin or stand alone (FF under the hood).

You cannot change it in its current release.

Here are more details:

> Prism is a simple XULRunner based
>   browser that hosts web applications
>   without the normal web browser user
>   interface. Prism is based on a concept
>   called Site Specific Browsers (SSB).
>   An SSB is an application with an
>   embedded browser designed to work
>   exclusively with a single web
>   application. It doesn’t have the
>   menus, toolbars and accoutrements of a
>   normal web browser. Some people have
>   called it a "distraction free browser"
>   because none of the typical browser
>   chrome is used. An SSB also has a
>   tighter integration with the OS and
>   desktop than a typical web application
>   running through a web browser.

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Prism

Answer (score 1):

I think it uses the default browser on your system. This will depend on what OS and environment you're running (Windows? OS X? KDE/Gnome on Linux?).

On Windows, go to Control Panel -> Programs -> Set Default Programs, select Firefox, and set as default.

Comment: Actually, this isn't true. It opens its own browser, which is really just Firefox minus a few things. You can't change it.